# Firebase Remote Config loading strategies for a/b testing

Tags: firebase, ab-testing, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/firebase-remote-config-loading.html

The article explains strategy #3

> When your user starts up your app, you immediately call
>   activateFetched(). This will apply any old values you've previously
>   fetched from the cloud. And then your user can immediately start
>   interacting with your app. In the meantime, you kick off an
>   asynchronous fetch() call to fetch new values from the cloud. And in
>   the completion handler for this call… you do nothing. Heck, you don't
>   even need add a completion handler in the first place. Those values
>   you fetched from the cloud will remain stored locally on the device
>   until your user calls activateFetched the next time they start your
>   app.

I wonder if the above strategy is ok when we are doing A/B testing.

Since the strategy is ignoring the fetched value until user opens the app next time, I wonder it would skew the A/B testing result?